# Laurent series and residues $f(z^2)$

Tags: complex-analysis, laurent-series

If $f(z)$ is analytic in $ 0 < |z| < n$, what is the residue of the function $f(z^2)$ at $z = 0$?

**Attempt**
If $f(z)$ has a pole of order n at $z=0$ it seems like the residue of $f(z^2)$ would just be the coefficient of the $a_{-n}$ term of the Laurent series for $f(z)$, since the Laurent series for 
$$
f(z) = \frac{a_{-n}}{z^{n}} + \cdots + \frac{a_{-2}}{z^{2}} + \frac{a_{-1}}{z} + a_{0} + a_{1}z + a_{2}z^2 + \cdots
$$
and $z^{n^{2}} = z^{2n}$ is this right?

Comment: Welcome to math stack exchange.  Since this is a learning community, we expect you to post your own ideas with the problem.  Please edit your post to include what you have tried and where (specifically) you are having difficulties.

Answer (score 0):

You should check your definition of Residue, is not the $a_{-n}$ coefficient in the Laurent expansion but the $a_{-1}$ one.

If $f$ has a pole of order $n$ at $z=0$ then
$$
f(z)=a_{-n}z^{-n} + \cdots + a_{-1}z^{-1} + \sum_{k=0}^{\infty}a_kz^k
$$
with $a_{-n} \neq 0$. Of course $Res(f,0)=a_{-1}$. Then around $0$, we have that if $g(z)=f(z^2)$ then 
\begin{align}
g(z)=f(z^2) & =a_{-n}z^{-2n} + \cdots + a_{-1}z^{-2} + \sum_{k=0}^{\infty}a_kz^{2k}\\
& = b_{-2n}z^{-2n} + \cdots + b_{-1}z^{-1} + \sum_{k=0}^{\infty}b_kz^{k}\\
\end{align}
where 
$$
b_j=\left\{ 
\begin{array}{cc}
a_{j/2} & \text{ if } j \in 2 \mathbb{Z} \\ 
0 & \text{in other case}
\end{array} \right.
$$
Since $b_{-2n}=a_{-n} \neq 0$ then $g$ has a pole of order $2n$ at $z=0$ and $Res(g,0)=b_{-1}=0$.

Now is clear that this still holds even if $f$ has not a finite order pole, since the residue of $g$ at $z=0$ will still be $b_{-1}=0$. Thus supposing that $f$ has a pole of order $n$ at $0$ only helps to get that $g$ has a pole of order $2n$ at $0$.

> Then we can conclude that $f(z^2)$ has residue $0$ at $z=0$