# Find the residue of the function $g(z)=f(z^2)$ at a given point.

Tags: complex-analysis, functions, residue-calculus, analyticity

Let $f(z)$ be analytic in $0<|z|<R$. Find the residue of the function $g(z)=f(z^2)$ at $z_0=0$.

I am looking for a solution to this problem.

My thoughts: 
I know in order to find the residue of a function, I first need to find the singularities.  Unfortunately this problem has me a little stumped on where to start because it didn't give me a function the way I've traditionally seen them.

Comment: Presumably $z_0 = 0$ is meant.  That's the only interesting point here.

Comment: All you need is that it's analytic in $0 < |z| < R$.

Comment: @RobertIsrael you are absolutely right. I've fixed it, thank you!

Comment: Duplicate of this one http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1267207/laurent-series-and-residues-fz2/1267227#1267227

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $z_0 = 0$, take the Laurent series $\displaystyle f(z) = \sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty a_n z^n$ of $f$.
Then $g(z) = f(z^2) = \sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty}a_nz^{2n}$. Hence the coefficient of $z^{-1}$ in that series of $g$, which is the residue of $g$ is $0$.